# Scilab - find the corresponding row or column of a specific number in the matrix

Tags: matrix, row, scilab

Suppose I specify a matrix A like this:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

I want to know which column is 8 located in. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/find.html).

```
A = [8 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
indices = find(A==8);
indices =
           1.   8.
```